# upload multiple images and display them

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, web

i wont to upload malty images from FileUpload store theme in cookies and display the images  in an update penal in the same time i get only the last photo updated to the update anal

and this the code behind in C#  :

```
protected void addphoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile )
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < FileUpload1.PostedFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                string vale = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
                string path = Server.MapPath("").Replace("user", "pimg") + "\\" + vale;
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(path);
                b = "~/pimg/" + vale;
                //string test = "~/pimg/d13526f4-9713-48fa-bb5d-a37f27b0366e.png";
                if (Request.Cookies["aa"] == null)
                {
                    Response.Cookies["aa"].Value = b;
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Cookies["aa"].Value = Request.Cookies["aa"].Value + "|" + b;
                }
            }

        }

if (Request.Cookies["aa"] != null)
        {
            s = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["aa"].Value);
            string[] strarr = s.Split('|');
            foreach (var item in strarr)
            {
                //string html = "<a class='btn btn-primary' style='padding: 10px; margin: 10px' href='deletitem?myid=" + item.ProdectID + "'>" + item.Name + "</a>" + "";
                Image img = new Image();
                img.ImageUrl = item.ToString();
                img.Height = 150;
                img.Width = 100;
                UpdatePanel2.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(img);

            }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. It will work.

```
//This is your .aspx code. The AllowMultiple on FileUpload only works in .NET Framework 4.5+
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>

//This is your code behind
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFiles)
    {
        foreach (var file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
        {
            string value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string extension = new FileInfo(file.FileName).Extension;

            string path = Server.MapPath("~/pimg/" + value + extension);
            string virtualPath = "/pimg/" + value + extension;

            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
            img.Save(path);

            if (Request.Cookies["aa"] == null)
            {
                Response.Cookies["aa"].Value = virtualPath;
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Cookies["aa"].Value = Request.Cookies["aa"].Value + "|" + virtualPath;
            }
        }
    }

    if (Request.Cookies["aa"] != null)
    {
        string[] picArray = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["aa"].Value).Split('|');
        foreach (var item in picArray)
        {
            Image img = new Image();
            img.ImageUrl = item.ToString();
            img.Height = 150;
            img.Width = 100;
            UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(img);
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it doesn't work for you.